# ASP.NET Core 2.0 ==> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, development-environment

I have create 2 pages in  asp.net core 2.0, both pages Login/Register open successfully as you can see in attached screen shot but when I click on login or register button after fill up all detail which is in form ,its giving me below error, I already try with changing environment variable , but its not helping me , please help !

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 0HLF8F6V3DFJ3:00000002

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Modify your web.config file with the below. The web.config file is typically auto generated in the root folder of the application.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\projectName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
     <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
```

The web.config in its entirety should resemble the below (update "projectName.dll" for your project appropriately):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\projectName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" >
     <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```